# key word/phrase search against similarity Matrix in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite, similarity, keyword-search

I have a table of documents with the schema:

```
CREATE TABLE Frequency (
  docid VARCHAR(255),
  term VARCHAR(255),
  count int,
PRIMARY KEY(docid, term));
```

To find the similarity raw scores for all documents I would use:

```
SELECT a.term, b.term, sum(a.count * b.count) 
FROM Frequency a, Frequency b
Where a.term = b.term
```

I am not sure why this works, but it did on test data to do D*DT, where DT is transpose of D.

I now need to compute the query/text string similarity for terms something like "congress gun laws"

I believe this involves unions and group by, but all my query attempts fail e.g.,:

```
SELECT *
FROM Frequency a, Frequency b, Frequency c
Where a.term = b.term 
UNION
SELECT  a.docid, 'congress' as term, 1 as count 
UNION
SELECT  b.docid , 'gun' as term, 1 as count
UNION 
SELECT  c.docid , 'laws' as term, 1 as count 
Group by docid;
```

I am new to this kind of SQL and would appreciate a narrative as I am trying to understand 
What I am doing as well.

Please explain why the first query works and how I could approach the second.

Comment: How is "similarity" defined in this case?

Comment: The count column lists the number of concurrences of a an term individual term e.g., "congress".

Comment: So for a single term it would be the doument

Comment: I need do similarity for a string of terms "congress+ gun +laws" and want to determine the raw count for those terms e.g., output rows: of docid "A term Congress term gun term laws count 5 5

Comment: Nobody understands what you want. Show some example records and the desired result.

Comment: You may want to not post Coursera assignment problems word for word on Stackoverflow... https://class.coursera.org/datasci-001

Answer (score 2):

To put it simply, what we really want to do here is to add the new tuples to the table, and then compare this new table to the old one using the matrix transpose operation you mentioned above. What you would need is to 'mark' these new keywords so that you could use them for a conditional in your query. So this

```
SELECT b.docid, b.term, SUM(a.count * b.count) 
FROM (SELECT * FROM Frequency
      UNION
      SELECT  'q' as docid, 'congress' as term, 1 as count 
      UNION
      SELECT  'q' as docid, 'gun' as term, 1 as count
      UNION 
      SELECT  'q' as docid, 'laws' as term, 1 as count 
     ) a, Frequency b
WHERE a.term = b.term 
AND a.docid = 'q'
GROUP BY b.docid, b.term
ORDER BY SUM(a.count * b.count);
```

would give you the list of docids with the term and their respective similarity scores.

Comment: Thanks Very much! Spot on! Chris

Comment: This does not work in python script, it is running infinitely long. import sqlite3; reuters=sqlite3.connect('reuters.db'); c = reuters.cursor(); p=c.execute(~~ sql script ~~); c.fetechall();

Answer (score 0):

Your question and comments are incomprehensible.

But the following query shows the number of occurrences of the three terms for all documents that contain all three terms:

```
SELECT a.docid,
       a.count,
       b.count,
       c.count
FROM Frequency AS a
JOIN Frequency AS b ON a.docid = b.docid
JOIN Frequency AS c ON b.docid = c.docid
WHERE a.term = 'congress'
  AND b.term = 'gun'
  AND c.term = 'laws'
```

Comment: This code returns results but does not restrict the document to containing all three terms, e.g., docid "AA" terms congress, gun, laws:SELECT a.docid, a.term, a.count
FROM Frequency a
JOIN
(SELECT 'q' as docid, 'washington' as term, 1 as count 
UNION
SELECT 'q' as docid, 'taxes' as term, 1 as count
UNION 
SELECT 'q' as docid, 'treasury' as term, 1 as count)b
ON a.term = b.term 
WHERE a.term = 'washington'
OR a.term = 'taxes'
OR a.term ='treasury'
GROUP BY a.docid, a.term;
Any suggestion please.